# Laravel testing file upload and resize

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

I'm trying to develop something using the TDD way and I'm facing this problem I can't solve.

I'm uploading an image which is resized and store in database.

When I'm doing it manually (using my browser like a regular user) it works, but the test fail.

Here is my controller:

```
public function store(Product $product)
    {
        //$name = request('image')->store('products', 'public');

        $name = str_random(50).'.jpg';
        $path = storage_path('app/public/products/'.$name);

        $image = Image::make(request('image'));
        $image->fit(400, 400);
        $image->save($path);

        $product->photos()->save(new Photo([
            'name' => $name
        ]));

        return redirect($product->adminPath());
    }
```

and here is my test

```
public function a_user_can_add_photos_to_the_product()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        $this->signIn();

        $product = ProductFactory::create();

        Storage::fake('public');

        $this->post($product->adminPath('/photos'), [
            'image' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('photo.jpg')
        ])->assertRedirect($product->adminPath());

        $product->load(['photos']);

        tap($product->photos->first(), function ($photo) {
            $this->assertInstanceOf('App\Photo', $photo);

            Storage::disk('public')->assertExists($photo->name);
        });

        $this->assertEquals(1, $product->photos->count());
    }
```

At this point the test will fail, but If i comment the resize part and use the store method on the request like this:

```
Tests\Feature\ManageProductPhotoTest::a_user_can_add_photos_to_the_product
Unable to find a file at path [pJ1Zd19XT0aF9fc5W1famc3n7WwxBt3L9MDB0yRJNlVYcWkMwk.jpg].
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

```
public function store(Product $product)
    {
        $name = request('image')->store('products', 'public');

        /*$name = str_random(50).'.jpg';
        $path = storage_path('app/public/products/'.$name);

        $image = Image::make(request('image'));
        $image->fit(400, 400);
        $image->save($path);*/

        $product->photos()->save(new Photo([
            'name' => $name
        ]));

        return redirect($product->adminPath());
    }
```

The test passes.

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: What do you get when you remove the `Storage::fake('public');` line and add the resize and save part again in the `store` function?

Comment: When an error fail then here should be a problem with the code. You are right about the code that it's working fine if you are using it from the browser, but you should also check the error log and check your tests to see if you are sending the exact request that you should send. this way you'll find the problem very easily.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I have the same problem - it's to do with the storage fake - Image is expecting the image to be in a directory and not finding it - but I can't find a way of testing and mocking Image to avoid creating real files to resize